# Can any polynomial be written as a linear factorization?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, factoring

I had the task of writing $f = x^4 + 3 x^3 − 35 x^2 − 39 x + 70 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. as a linear factorization by guessing the first two null points.

I found $x=-2$ and $x=1$ and did a polynomial division accordingly.
Now, for the last two zero points I've calculated $x=-7$ and $x=5$ with the $pq$-formula.

**Now my question:** Can I now directly write $f=(x+7)(x-5)(x+2)(x-1)$ or do I have to prove that I can do the polynomial division with $f$? Also under the task there was the hint that

> You can take advantage of the fact that an integer
> zero of a polynomial is a divisor of the absolute term.

Does the hint change anything about the need to prove what I mentioned above?

Comment: If you want to double check your answer you can just expand out $(x+7)(x-5)(x+2)(x-1)$ and see if you get your polynomial back.

Comment: Based on my experience, with problems of this generic type, I infer that the intent of the problem composer is that the problem be **initially** attacked via the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).  Initially, you have no guarantee that any of the equation's 4 roots will be real, or than any of the real roots will be rational.  Despite this however, this is still the standard initial attack approach.

Comment: I would say state that you're using that hint and show that you've found the four roots. You may want to mention that that's all the roots (since it's a quartic) and possibly point out that the polynomial is monic, so you have the correct leading coefficient.

Comment: Why the down votes? I think it's a reasonably well posed question.